# move_upload_file failing in cakephp application

Tags: php, cakephp

i have a cakephp application.
In which i want to introduce file upload functionality.

I am using move_upload_file function to upload the file which is returning false in my case
I have added code comments inline with the code to show the parameters passed to the move_uploaded_file function in runtime.

Please find my code below

```
$id = $this->Auth->user('userid');
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
            ]);
    $target_dir = "C/Docs/Misc/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['resume']['name']); //_$FILES has the proper file uploaded from the web client in the resume index.
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {

        //if($resume["size"]>0){
            try {
             //move_uploaded_file is returning false. 
             //first parameter to the function has the file name for e.g. doc.text
             //second parameter is C/Docs/Misc/doc.text
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['name'], $target_file)) {
                Log::info("The file ". basename( $_FILES['resume']['name']). " has been uploaded.");
            } else {
                Log::error("Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.");
            }
            }catch(Exception $e){
                Log::error("Sorry there was an error uploading file ",$e);
            }
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);

            $user->resume = $target_file;
            //$fileData = fread(fopen($resume["tmp_name"],"r"),$resume["size"]);
            //$user->resume = $fileData;
        //}else{
            //$//user->resume = null;
        //}
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['controller'=> 'job', 'action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
```

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: `$_FILES['resume']['name']`, you probably want `$_FILES['resume']['tmp_name']`.

Comment: @JonStirling...yes you are right...thanks